Update Chrome, python code to create png does not longer work
I have code which creates a screenshot from internally created html files. Chrome issued an update and since then we can no longer take proper screenshot. Each screenshot has a black border at the bottom and it also doesn't show the entire html.
Is there a solution without downgrading Chrome.
with open("{}.html".format(filename), "w+") as file:
    file.write(string)


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("no-sandbox");
chrome_options.add_argument("headless");
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080");
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
 

print(os.getcwd())

browser.get(os.path.join('file://{}.html').format(filename).replace("\\", "/"))
#browser.get(os.path.join('file://' + os.getcwd() + '/{}.html').format(filename).replace("\\", "/"))

time.sleep(10)

browser.save_screenshot('{}.png'.format(filename))
browser.quit()

im = Image.open('{}.png'.format(filename))   

left = 0
top = 0
right = 1080
bottom = 1080

im1 = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
im1.save('{}.png'.format(filename))

